# Powershell script getting variables from a text file

Tags: file, powershell, variables, text

Im trying to do a script from powershell that reads a text file like this:

```
text1,data1,data2
text2,data1,data2
```

and use that data in a command for each row of the file.

thank you for the help.

edit:

I think that i can use the command

```
while read line do
   if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
      (commands here for each row, but i cant find how to get the variable)
   fi
done < file.txt
```

mi text file is like this:

```
prueba1,vSwitch0,10
prueba2,vSwitch0,20
prueba3,vSwitch0,30
```

and i have to put that data into this code:

```
New-VirtualPortGroup -Name prueba1 -VirtualSwitch vSwitch0 -VlanId 10
```

Comment: Could you expand on this? "and use that data in a command for each row of the file."

Comment: What have you tried already? Please show some effort and code and indicate a specific problem. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: edited, thank you for the repply

Comment: are you trying to produce a bash script or a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your text file appears to be comma delimited without a header. You could use `Import-CSV` with the `-Header` flag to import the data into a PowerShell object. Then loop over the data in the object.

```
$Data = Import-CSV C:\path\to\file.csv -Header 'Name','vSwitch','Id'
ForEach ($Entry in $Data) {
    New-VirtualPortGroup -Name $Entry.Name -VirtualSwitch $Entry.vSwitch -VlanId $Entry.Id
}
```